# All view controllers and navigation view controllers end below the status bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

All my `view controllers` and `navigation view controller` end below the status bar. How to avoid such behavior, so that they don't use the full screen.

I'm using `xCode9` with `iOS11`.

I've played with `edgesForExtendedLayout` property, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met same problem and finally I found out that the issue is with safe area in Xcode 9.

You can solve this by 2 ways

**1.** Uncheck use safe area support

[image]

**2.** If you are using `Autolayout` adjust your `toplayout` constraint value as that achive FullScreen

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to set `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: UInt(0))`